# I wish create 2 pages in Next.JS with pagination and args between the 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, next.js, nodes

What I want:
Create 2 page in Next.JS in React.JS that can do the following:

- User lands in the page 1 (/home) where there is a search bar
- User type in the page 1 type what he wants in the search bar and validate the form
- User is redirected to the page 2 (/search/:parameter) with the query string in the URL parameter...
- Make an HTTP request into the page 2 with the arg passed
- Show to the user the result of the http request

What I tried to do and I didn't successfully to do that

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import Link from 'next/link'

function submitForm() {
  if(process.browser) {
    alert(document.getElementById('subvalue').value)
  }
}

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Head>
          <title>Reddit Feed App</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>

        <main>
          <form action="#" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Search for any subreddit :</label>
            <input type="text" id="subvalue"/>
            <span onClick={submitForm()} >Submit</span>
          </form>
        </main>
         ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So, I'm stuck I'm blocked I already did not succeed to make my submit form function working. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the value of the input on submit and [programatically changing the current route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) :

You can get the value by making a ref to the `<input />` element :

Your first page should look like this `/pages/index.js`

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some validations here
    router.push(`search/${inputRef.current.value}`);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input name="second_page" type="number" ref={inputRef} />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This will get you to `/search/[the value you submitted]`.

In order to create that dynamic page you should use the [Dynamic API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes).

Just create a file named `/pages/[paramPassed].js`

I made an example with the jsonplaceholder api :

```js
export default function Search({ res }) {
  return (
    <div>
      Here's the result :
      <pre>
        <code>{JSON.stringify(res)}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const { paramPassed } = params;

  const req = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${paramPassed}`
  );
  const res = await req.json();

  return {
    props: { res } // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

The `getServerSideProps` allows you to set default params to your page component before rendering it.
You can use the fetch API or SWR inside your React components for remote data fetching; or use Next.js' data fetching methods for initial data population.